# Fillup cell depending on value of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, if

So I want to fill up certain cells with certain values. I want to use the `IF` function. I have the following data:

```
4271423/421424/4237168/4246332=D917/F222
4271423/421424/4237168/4253485=D917/F222/J008
4271423/421424/4237168/4246332/4224002=D917/F222/J008/F214
4271423/421424=D917
4246332=F222
```

I made this function:

=IF(F:F="4271423/421424/4237168/4246332","D917/F222",IF(F:F=,"4271423/421424/4237168/4253485","D917/F222/J008",IF(F:F="4271423/421424/4237168/4246332/4224002","D917/F222/J008/F214",IF(F:F="4271423/421424","D917",IF(F:F="4271423/421424/4237168
","D917/F222",IF(F:F="4246332","F222")))))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this for example in `E1`:

```
=IF(F1="4271423/421424/4237168/4246332","D917/F222",IF(F1="4271423/421424/4237168/4253485","D917/F222/J008",IF(F1="4271423/421424/4237168/4246332/4224002","D917/F222/J008/F214",IF(F1="4271423/421424","D917",IF(F1="4271423/421424/4237168","D917/F222",IF(TEXT(F1,"@")="4246332","F222",""))))))
```

Then you can copy the formula down.

Comment: WOW thanks for your help! you made my work easier! really appreciate it.

Comment: why did you wrote this: ,IF(TEXT(F1,"@")="  at the end? what is the function of this section of the formula

Comment: I wrote this because of `4246332`. I do not know your data type. All other values are not ambiguous, they are all text. But this one can be both text and a number. Since I don't know, I forced it to become text using `text` function. If in your data it was left as a number and the formula would try to check if it is equal to `"4246332"` (text), the formula would return `FALSE`.

Comment: ohh i see! very insightful i would never thought of that haha but im also new to excel, so maybe someday i will be as good as you haha